# Google DataStudio cannot take parameter from URL, but could I use Google Apps Script Google Data Studio data connector to pass the parameter value?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have a Google DataStudio Reports, with an "account ids filter", for example I may have 100 client accounts.

I want to share this report with these 100 accounts. But each account should only see their own report.

But Google DataStudio does not take parameter from url, so I cannot pass account id value into the DataStudio report url to filter out the report accordingly.

I have a thought.  What if I use Google Apps Script to create a Google Data Studio data connector, and use this data connector as the data source for my Google DataStudio reports.

Then I will share this report with my 100 client accounts.

Each client account will access this report (the data source is Google Apps Script data connector). And the Google Apps Script data connector would run under this client's google account. and the Google Script will do the following jobs, authenticate the this account, know which account it is based on this account's google account, fetch the data of this account only , as data source for the Google DataStudio Report. This way, each client would get the report for himself/herself.

Would that work? Do anyone have resources or codes can share for this problem and this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your connector code, use `getEffectiveUser()` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser)) to get the user's Id and filter your data by that.
2. Using your connector, create a data source and enforce [viewer's credentials](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6371135?hl=en).
3. Create a dashboard from that data source.

When your clients view the dashboard, they will have to authorize the connector the first time. Then they will only see data that is applicable to them.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to the sample codes to Google Data Studio data connector to BigQuery that I can modify for my usage?

Comment: This connector connects to BigQuery: https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/chrome-ux-report (It does a lot of other things like caching to Firebase and Apps Script)

Comment: Thanks Minhaz, I will give a try. There is a lot of info to digest. A quick question, do you know the max size of the data source? or in other words, is this still limited by the Google Apps Script, URL Fetch response size - 50MB?

Comment: If you are doing UrlFetch, then you get limited by whatever quota there is in Apps Script. Details here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Minhaz, I am not familiar with the DataStudio Data Connector. This will be my next project. I used the Google built BigQuery Connector, our datastudio can use the 10 GB BigQuery table as data source. But if a customized data connector is built by myself, I only can use Google Apps Script, and according to the tutorial, I will display the response in a url, so my limitation is limited by Google Apps Script quotas. Are there any other ways for me to build Data Studio connector that can link to a data source (BigQuery table etc) with huge size, like a few GB?

Comment: 1) UrlFetch limit is 50MB/call. You can always make multiple calls. 2) You can get around the UrlFetch limit for BigQuery by using the BigQuery service in Apps Script (ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) 3) If you have a 10GB table in BigQuery, Data Studio does not bring in the entire table. Depending on your query/charts, Data Studio will bring in a small chunk / aggregated data.

Comment: "You can get around the UrlFetch limit for BigQuery by using the BigQuery service in Apps Script (ref: developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery)" - I already used BigQuery Services in Google Apps Script. It is a good quick tool that Google Apps Script could use advanced services and also could use all these Google/YouTube api calls directly. 

But I still have trouble to figure out how to "get around the UrlFetch limit for BigQuery by using the BigQuery service in Apps Script"? The tutorial of data connector is display the response in json fomat in response?

Comment: I used BigQuery service to fetch data from BigQuery, but to make a data studio data connector, I need to display data in json format in a web response format, right? so it would be limited by UrlFetch limit?

If this is a question for another thread instead of comments, I will create another thread. But thanks a lot, so far I got a lot of useful info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181984/discussion-between-searain-and-minhaz-kazi).

Comment: Minhaz, so when data studio connecting to the data source through the data connector, the data connector's final response size will be very small, just the aggregated data of these huge BigQuery tables, that needed to generate the charts, decided by the data connector's pre-defined fields and aggregation types.

As long as my "aggregated data that needed to generate the charts" is smaller than Google Apps Script quota limits, I will be fine. Right?